Stacked area plot missing single x-value data on upper bound
I have a stacked area plot with labels to the right for the values. Three values only appeared in the last bin of data, so they only have values for the upper bound of the x-axis. As a result they show up blank at the top. Is there a way for the plot to show a very thin bar for each of them on top of the stack?

Data:
time <- structure(list(Strategy = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,
7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L,
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L), levels = c("active immunization",
"immune response", "lipid metabolism", "microtubule stabilization",
"oxidative stress", "proteostasis network", "tau enzyme/PTM",
"cell regeneration/restoration", "general neuroprotection", "neuromodulator/transmission",
"non-pharmacological", "passive immunization", "tau aggregation",
"tau reduction", "energy metabolism", "epigenome/transcription",
"metal ion modulation", "neurotrophin pathway", "tau isoform imbalance correction",
"cellular senescence", "combination", "tau propagation"), class = "factor"),
    bin = c("2004-2009", "2004-2009", "2004-2009", "2004-2009",
    "2004-2009", "2004-2009", "2004-2009", "2010-2014", "2010-2014",
    "2010-2014", "2010-2014", "2010-2014", "2010-2014", "2010-2014",
    "2010-2014", "2010-2014", "2010-2014", "2010-2014", "2010-2014",
    "2010-2014", "2010-2014", "2015-2019", "2015-2019", "2015-2019",
    "2015-2019", "2015-2019", "2015-2019", "2015-2019", "2015-2019",
    "2015-2019", "2015-2019", "2015-2019", "2015-2019", "2015-2019",
    "2015-2019", "2015-2019", "2015-2019", "2015-2019", "2015-2019",
    "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024",
    "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024",
    "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024",
    "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024", "2020-2024",
    "2020-2024", "2020-2024"), N = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    2L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 12L, 6L,
    1L, 4L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 11L, 8L, 35L, 13L,
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 17L, 20L, 2L,
    26L, 21L, 8L, 27L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L
    ), mycolors = c("#97B1BD", "#FBFBB4", "#EBBD63", "#C4D367",
    "#D9B382", "#D9D7C9", "#C8EABC", "#97B1BD", "#FBFBB4", "#EBBD63",
    "#C4D367", "#D9B382", "#D9D7C9", "#C8EABC", "#F0D1E1", "#C3B4D0",
    "#E39699", "#A9A0B2", "#8DD3C7", "#E9877F", "#EED0CD", "#97B1BD",
    "#FBFBB4", "#EBBD63", "#C4D367", "#D9B382", "#D9D7C9", "#C8EABC",
    "#C3B4D0", "#E39699", "#A9A0B2", "#8DD3C7", "#E9877F", "#EED0CD",
    "#C7D98C", "#CDB7CE", "#BE88BF", "#DED7DA", "#CBE5C4", "#97B1BD",
    "#FBFBB4", "#EBBD63", "#C4D367", "#D9B382", "#D9D7C9", "#C8EABC",
    "#F0D1E1", "#C3B4D0", "#E39699", "#A9A0B2", "#8DD3C7", "#E9877F",
    "#EED0CD", "#C7D98C", "#CDB7CE", "#BE88BF", "#DED7DA", "#CBE5C4",
    "#C2ADC0", "#E4EB9C", "#FFED6F"), cum = c(0.5, 2, 5, 7.5,
    8.5, 9.5, 11, 4.5, 10.5, 13, 15.5, 17.5, 21.5, 30, 36.5,
    41.5, 46.5, 52, 62, 71, 74.5, 2, 12, 20.5, 22, 25.5, 34.5,
    48, 56.5, 63.5, 73, 94.5, 118.5, 125.5, 127, 128.5, 129.5,
    131.5, 134, 2, 14.5, 25.5, 27, 29.5, 39.5, 58, 69, 83, 106.5,
    121, 138.5, 157, 164, 168.5, 172.5, 175.5, 178, 179.5, 181.5,
    184, 186)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-61L))

Code:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

t_type <- "bin"
p3 <- ggplot(time, aes(x = get(t_type), y = N)) +
  geom_area(
    aes(group = Strategy, fill = Strategy), 
    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = unique(time$mycolors), 
    labels = unique(time$Strategy)
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = ~ filter(., get(t_type) == last(time[[t_type]])),
    aes(y = cum, label = Strategy), 
    direction = "y", 
    hjust = "left", 
    segment.color = 'gray',
    na.rm = TRUE,
    xlim = c(4.2, 6),
    ylim = c(0, 200)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 200), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.3))) +
  labs(x = "Year of study", y = "Number of evaluations") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    # text = element_text(family = "Arial"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
    legend.position = 'none'
  )


If you make the zero values explicit like so:
complete_time <- complete(time, Strategy, bin, fill = list(N = 0))

you get a more consistent plot:

Note that the "step" effect is removed. This is consistent with the stacked area interpretation where the area linearly changes between adjacent time periods. In your plot, some changes are shown as linear changes, while other changes are shown as instantaneous.

Thanks, that does solve it, though the realization is that I probably want something more akin to an alluvial or stacked bar chart

Could you add a half bin point on the plot? So that each bin has a start and end effectively?
I've done a version where the values are equal to half way between your different bins without too much trouble I'm sure.
I only changed three lines (commented)
library(dplyr)
#maily added this and used it in the plot
time2 <- bind_rows(time, mutate(time, bin = gsub("-.*","",bin)))

t_type <- "bin"
p3 <- ggplot(time2, aes(x = get(t_type), y = N)) +
  geom_area(
    aes(group = Strategy, fill = Strategy), 
    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = unique(time$mycolors), 
    labels = unique(time$Strategy)
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = ~ filter(., get(t_type) == last(time[[t_type]])),
    aes(y = cum, label = Strategy),
    direction = "y",
    hjust = "left",
    segment.color = 'gray',
    na.rm = TRUE,

#also changed limits on the labels
    xlim = c(8.2, 12),
    ylim = c(0, 200)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 200), expand = c(0, 0)) +

  #also forced to only show breaks in original dataset
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.3)), breaks = time$bin) +
  labs(x = "Year of study", y = "Number of evaluations") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    # text = element_text(family = "Arial"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
    legend.position = 'none'
  )
p3



Also in addition to @axeman 's answer. Here is the data.table method if you want to fill in your zeros:
# fill in zero values
setkeyv(time, cols = c("Strategy", t_type))
time <- time[CJ(Strategy, get(t_type), unique = TRUE)]
setnafill(time, fill = 0, cols = 'N')

Modified from suggestions here to adopt a variable as a column name and avoid line wrapping.
